# How to add white space in the line chart plot points?

Tags: highcharts

Please refer to the following image.

[image]

I need the plotting points like the image with the specific color.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `border/fillColor` parameters for marker.

http://jsfiddle.net/XWGFs/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.fillColor